# Sending Push notifications to multiple apps under the same project in Firebase

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible for two or more apps under the same project to receive push notifications with the same server key? If so, how can this be done?

Comment: yes it is possible.. just apply the same things for others app

Comment: Add the same thing, do you mean using the same google-service.json file, where just the package name is different?

Comment: all different. only the ways to apply it still same.